# Why am I getting an "out of range for bigint" error when deleting records through a function in Postgresql?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm working on writing a postgresql stored procedure to delete records from a table based on a certain criteria. If I find a match, then I delete the record.

**Here is my stored procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DeleteSomeRecords(keys_param character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM public.SomeTable
    WHERE keyvalue = ANY(keys_param::bigint[]);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The field keyvalue is defined as bigint.

**Here is how I call it from PgAdmin 4:**

```
SELECT * FROM DeleteSomeRecords('{9226086781768122240,9506724121199784302}')
```

**I get the following error.**

> ERROR:  value "9226086781768122240" is out of range for type bigint
>   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM public.SomeTable
>       WHERE keyvalue= ANY(keys_param::bigint[])" PL/pgSQL function DeleteSomeRecords(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement

What am I doing wrong here?

Is there a better way to write this function?

I'm calling this function through a C#/.Net application using NpgSql.
I have a List values which I convert to a comma separated string:

```
string sKeyValues = "{" + string.Join(",", keyValue) + "}";
```

Thanks

Comment: `9226086781768122240` is bigger than the biggest possible value of a `bigint` (which is `9223372036854775807`). What's the type of `keyvalue` in table `SomeTable`?

Comment: It is defined as a bigint.

Comment: Then it is not possible to have `9226086781768122240` in it. Either handle out-of-range values before casting to `bigint`, or cast to `numeric` as @ClodoaldoNeto suggested.

Comment: Regardless of your issue, I have to wonder why someone would join an array of longs into a string in C# just to send them to the PostgreSQL to be parsed back to an array of longs (the function doesn't seem to have any added value either)... Any reason you're not just executing `DELETE FROM public."SomeTable" WHERE keyvalue=@p`, and passing a .NET array of long to Npgsql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to numeric:

```
WHERE keyvalue = ANY(keys_param::numeric[])
```